# Adding values to a list with an array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a list using this class:

```
public class Edges
{
    public int no_piece;
    public int edge;
    public int[,] edge_pixels;
}
```

This is to assemble a puzzle. I am trying to save the characteristics of each piece this way: no_piece - the number of the piece /// edge - which edge (top as '0', left as '1', bottom as '2' and right as '3') /// edge_pixels - the number of pixels for each channel, for example:
               edge_pixels[0,x] would have the values of each pixel of an edge, of n piece);

This is the way I tried;

```
List<Edges> edges_list = new List<Edges>();
for (i = 0; i < number of pieces; i++)
                {
                    for (y = vector_coordinates[i,1]; y < vector_coordinates[i,3]; y++)
                    {//vectors with top and bottom coordinates of the piece in the original image
                        for (x = vector_coordinates[i,0]; x < vector_coordinates[i,2]; x++)
                        {// the same goes for x but left and right
                            if (y == vector_coordinates[i, 1]) //top
                            {
                                for (aux_rgb = 0; aux_rgb < 3; aux_rgb++)
                                {
                                    Edges edge = new Edges();

                                    edge.no_piece = i;
                                    edge.edge = 1;
                                    edge.edge_pixels[aux_rgb, aux_count_pixel] = (int)dataPtr[aux_rgb];

                                    edges_list.Add(edge);
                                }                                    
                            }
                            aux_count_pixel++;
                         }
                      (...)
```

But it doesn't work and I don´t understand why. I'm not sure if I made myself clear. Thank you

Comment: "Doesn't work" can mean so many things, and is rarely a good problem description. Try to distill the problem down into a SSCCE.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I would like to help but I have no idea what you want to do. Please try to describe what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
List<Edges> edges_list = new List<Edges>();
for (i = 0; i < number of pieces; i++)
                {
                    for (y = vector_coordinates[i,1]; y < vector_coordinates[i,3]; y++)
                    {//vectors with top and bottom coordinates of the piece in the original image
                        for (x = vector_coordinates[i,0]; x < vector_coordinates[i,2]; x++)
                        {// the same goes for x but left and right
                            if (y == vector_coordinates[i, 1]) //top
                            {
                                Edges edge = new Edges();
                                edges_list.Add(edge);
                                edge.no_piece = i;
                                for (aux_rgb = 0; aux_rgb < 3; aux_rgb++)
                                {                                    
                                    edge.edge = 1;
                                    edge.edge_pixels[aux_rgb, aux_count_pixel] = (int)dataPtr[aux_rgb];
                                }                                    
                            }
                            aux_count_pixel++;
                         }
```

Comment: Please add some more text explaining why you think this solves the OP:s question. (I understand what part of the code you changed, but it's not necessarily obvious to other readers.)